# Javascript: Closure Compiler Output

Tags: javascript

I've come across a line of code output from Google's Closure Compiler and I'm stumped as to what is does, since I don't recognize the syntax.

```
a && !a.jquery && ("string" === typeof a ? a = b(a) : !("addClass" in a) && (!("removeClass" in a) && !("attr" in a) && !("not" in a)) && (a = b(a)));
```

If anyone could break this down for me, I'd greatly appreciate it. Moreover, an example in plain Javascript would be even more helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What syntax don't you recognize?

Comment: Perhaps syntax was the wrong term. This code block appears to be a bunch of nested IF statements. However, it's the nested parens that are giving me trouble as to the number of nest levels.

Comment: Figuring out what this code does might not be very useful, since it's from  Closure Compiler.  That means this is minified code generated by a computer.  A programmer wouldn't normally write this line.

Comment: I added some newlines to this code (as well as moved around some of the parenthesis), not sure if it helps: http://pastebin.com/7naKEey0

Comment: It's checking if `a` is a jQuery object - first via looking for a `.jquery` member, then looking for all of a set of characteristic jQuery methods. If not, it's calling some sort of function on `a` (perhaps `b` is an alias for `jQuery`, adding the jQuery wrapper if it wasn't there before).